# How to test json array attribute for size in Jasper pdf report

Tags: json, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I'm designing Pdf report in tibco jaspersoft studio. The report is using json datasource.  There is array of children in json file:

```
{
    ...,
    "children":[],
    ...
}
```

I'm using subreport inside band which renders the children (when they are there) just fine. The children array might be empty (like the example above) and i want to assign  to containing band so it will disappear when children is empty.

I tried to declare field:

```
<field name="children" class="java.lang.Object[]">
        <fieldDescription>
               <![CDATA[children]]>    
        </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

and

```
<printWhenExpression>   
     <![CDATA[$F{children}.length!=0]]>
</printWhenExpression>
```

but the expression editor keeps complaining with message

> The current expression is not valid. Please verify it!

I also tried some wariants with NOT(EQUALS()) with same results. Expression editor keeps highlighting .length!=0 as error.

**Update**
It appears that errors shown in expression editor are not real errors and report will compile. The condition works if the array is empty. Otherwise i get another error

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for JSON
>   field "children" of class [Ljava.lang.Object;.

children are some structured POJOS, instances of Object indeed.

so far I worked this around by adding some extra boolean flags in json data. I don't like this solution but it's good enough for my customer

Comment: What is the language of your report (*language* attribute of *jasperReport*)?

Comment: <queryString language="json">
  <![CDATA[]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: Not the *sueryString*, the language of report

Comment: Now I'm not sure. The report is made in studio which generate .jrxml files and then compile it to .jasper files. Real output is Czech language, but encoding is UTF8 so don't think it matters. We run this report using java web application.

Answer (score 0):

[Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k) in comment are refereeing to this:

Your expressions will work correctly if you use `language="java"`  or `language="groovy"` on the `jasperReport` tag, my guess is that you are currently using `language="javascript"`

For more information on **Expressions Scripting Language** see [JRCompiler API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRCompiler.html)

To change it either edit the `jrxml`, setting correct attribute, or use the IDE properties on the report node (base node).

Answer (score 0):

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{children}.toString().equals( "[]" )]]></printWhenExpression>
```

This code work for me,